# Unauthorized 401 (Missing credentials) using Passport JWT in NestJS

Tags: typescript, jwt, nestjs, passport.js, passport-jwt

I'm trying to use JWT to authenticate my users in my NestJS API but I always get the same error: Unauthorized 401.

Let me show you my code before I tell you about my investigation that came up empty:

## JWT generation (this code works correctly)

> auth.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { UserModule } from 'src/user/user.module';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { LocalAuthController } from './local/local-auth.controller';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt/jwt.strategy';

@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule,
        JwtModule.register({
            secretOrPrivateKey: 'a'
        }),
        UserModule],
    providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy],
    controllers: [LocalAuthController]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

> auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from 'src/user/user.service';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { LocalAuthDto } from './local/local-auth.dto';
import { AccountType, User } from 'src/user/entity/user.entity';
import { JwtPayload } from './jwt/jwt.payload';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(
        private readonly userService: UserService,
        private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
    ) {}

    async signinLocal(localAuthDto: LocalAuthDto): Promise<any | null> {
        const user = await this.userService.findOneByEmailOrUsername(localAuthDto.emailOrUsername, true);

        if (user === null || !(await bcrypt.compare(localAuthDto.password, user.password)))
            throw new UnauthorizedException("Invalid credentials");

        const payload: JwtPayload = { sub: user.uuid };

        return this.jwtService.sign(payload);
    }
}
```

> local-auth.controller.ts

```
import { Body, Controller, Post, Request, UnauthorizedException, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ApiTags } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { LocalAuthDto } from './local-auth.dto';

@ApiTags("auth")
@Controller('auth/local')
export class LocalAuthController {

    constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

    @Post('signin')
    async signin(@Body() localAuthDto: LocalAuthDto) {
        return await this.authService.signinLocal(localAuthDto);
    }
}
```

> jwt.payload.ts

```
export class JwtPayload {
    sub: string;
}
```

## JWT Usage (this doesnt work)

> jwt.strategy.ts

```
import { Injectable, Logger, UnauthorizedException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { ExtractJwt } from "passport-jwt";
import { Strategy } from "passport-local";

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'jwt') {
    constructor() {
        super({
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
            ignoreExpiration: true,
            secretOrKey: 'a',
        });
    }

    async validate(payload: any) {
        return payload;
    }
}
```

> jwt.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable, Logger, UnauthorizedException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AuthGuard } from "@nestjs/passport";

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
    private readonly logger = new Logger(JwtAuthGuard.name);

    handleRequest(err, user, info) {
        this.logger.error(err, user, info);
        
        if (err || !user) {
            throw err || new UnauthorizedException();
        }
        return user;
    }

}
```

## Where I use the JwtAuthGuard

> app.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Get, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ApiBearerAuth } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { JwtAuthGuard as JwtAuthGuard } from './auth/jwt/jwt.guard';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
    constructor() {}

    @Get()
    healthCheck(): string {
        return "API started";
    }

    @ApiBearerAuth()
    @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
    @Get("authCheck")
    authenticationGuardCheck(): string {
        return "It works";
    }

}
```

## My investigation

First I extracted a generated JWT by my code :
`eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIwNGRkM2MyNi03YjA4LTQ2MWEtYTA4OS05YWRkOTgzZjZmODUiLCJpYXQiOjE2NzA3NzU2MzR9.0MuojBY0_i5Losa6IgPrB2A2py-XrLoueMc4Mk1PUrY`
It contains the good uuid and is well signed with the secret: `a`

Passport did not give me any errors in the console and just returned me `Unauthorized 401`

So I tried to display more informations and i found this code (in jwt.guard.ts):

```
handleRequest(err, user, info) {
        this.logger.error(err, user, info);
        
        if (err || !user) {
            throw err || new UnauthorizedException();
        }
        return user;
    }
```

Now when I send a request i get this into the console :
[passport "errors"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJTDq.png)

So I ask NestJS to print my requests and my token is present: [request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKPg9.png)

And now I'm stuck here, I don't understand why passport cant get my token in the request headers.
You are my last chance ;(

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `JwtStrategy` you import `Strategy` from `passport-local` instead of `passport-jwt`. This means that passport is looking for `req.body.username` and `req.body.password` instead of actually caring about the `JWT` you are sending via the `authorization` header. Import `Strategy` from `passport-jwt` instead and this should be resovled

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't see this for 8 hours.